# Destructuring of union types in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way (similar to pattern matching from functional languages) to destructure a union type in TypeScript, i.e. some construct like:

```
var a: Foo | Bar = ...;

a match {
   case f: Foo => //it's a Foo!
   case b: Bar => //it's a Bar!
}
```

If there is no such construct - are there any technical difficulties in creating such construct?

Answer (score 13):

TypeScript understands [Type Guards](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-guards) as a way of decomposing union types. There are several ways you can use this.

If `Foo` or `Bar` is a class, you can use `instanceof`:

```
if (a instanceof Foo) { a.doFooThing(); }
```

If they're interfaces, you can write a user-defined type guard:

```
function isFoo(f: any): f is Foo {
    // return true or false, depending....
}
if (isFoo(a)) {
   a.doFooThing();
} else {
   a.doBarThing();
}
```

You can also use `typeof a === 'string'` to test for primitive types in a union (`string`, `number`, or `boolean`)

Comment: if it is possible using type guards, are there any plan to add a special pattern-matching-like syntax (which would be a syntactic sugar over a series of ifs with type guards) that would be much more user-friendly?

Comment: in const form:    
`const resourceIsBeaver = (
  resource: Beaver | Lumber,
): resource is Beaver => resource.objectID === "Beaver"`