# how to write filter over union type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following example to illustrate what I'm trying to get.

```
const v1: { type: "S"; payload: string } = { type: "S", payload: "test" };
const v2: { type: "N"; payload: number } = { type: "N", payload: 123 };

type Actions = typeof v1 | typeof v2;

const findByType = <A extends Actions>(type: A["type"]) => (
    action: Actions
): action is A => action.type === type;

const filterWithBothNameAndType = [v1, v2].filter(findByType<typeof v1>("S"));
console.log(filterWithBothNameAndType[0].payload.trim());

const findByTypeDoesntWork = <A extends Actions, T extends A["type"]>(type: T) => (
    action: Actions
): action is A => action.type === type;

const filterWithJustType = [v1, v2].filter(findByTypeDoesntWork("S"));
console.log(filterWithJustType[0].payload.trim());
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20v1%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22S%22%3B%20payload%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22S%22%2C%20payload%3A%20%22test%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20v2%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22N%22%3B%20payload%3A%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22N%22%2C%20payload%3A%20123%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Actions%20%3D%20typeof%20v1%20%7C%20typeof%20v2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20findByType%20%3D%20%3CA%20extends%20Actions%3E(type%3A%20A%5B%22type%22%5D)%20%3D%3E%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20action%3A%20Actions%0D%0A)%3A%20action%20is%20A%20%3D%3E%20action.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20type%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20filterWithBothNameAndType%20%3D%20%5Bv1%2C%20v2%5D.filter(findByType%3Ctypeof%20v1%3E(%22S%22))%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(filterWithBothNameAndType%5B0%5D.payload.trim())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20findByTypeDoesntWork%20%3D%20%3CA%20extends%20Actions%2C%20T%20extends%20A%5B%22type%22%5D%3E(type%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20action%3A%20Actions%0D%0A)%3A%20action%20is%20A%20%3D%3E%20action.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20type%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20filterWithJustType%20%3D%20%5Bv1%2C%20v2%5D.filter(findByTypeDoesntWork(%22S%22))%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(filterWithJustType%5B0%5D.payload.trim())%3B%0D%0A)

I have function `findByType` that has right type information and I have function `filterWithJustType` that has api that I like, but it loses type information. I want api to be just `filter("S")` without passing generic type. So far [it looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833859/74167) it will only work with classes and `instaceof` but I wanted to make it work with plain objects.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Exclude` or `Extract` as mentioned by the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types), for example:

```
type T00 = Exclude<"a" | "b" | "c" | "d", "a" | "c" | "f">;  // "b" | "d"
type T01 = Extract<"a" | "b" | "c" | "d", "a" | "c" | "f">;  // "a" | "c"

type T02 = Exclude<string | number | (() => void), Function>;  // string | number
type T03 = Extract<string | number | (() => void), Function>;  // () => void
```

Comment: Other type helper that might help in this case is Pick<>

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @artem for giving me idea of ActionMap, I added actionCreator so that it ensures that keys and payload types are in sync, and behold:

```
type ActionMap = {
    S: string;
    N: number;
};

function actionCreatorFactory<
    T extends keyof ActionMap,
    P extends ActionMap[T]
>(type: T) {
    return function actionCreator(payload: P) {
        return { type, payload };
    };
}

const actionCreators = {
    s: actionCreatorFactory("S"),
    n: actionCreatorFactory("N"),
};

const v1 = actionCreators.s("test");
const v2 = actionCreators.n(123);

const findByType = <
    T extends keyof ActionMap,
    A extends { type: T; payload: ActionMap[T] }
>(
    type: T
) => (action: A): action is A => action.type === type;

const filterWithJustType = [v1, v2].filter(findByType("S"));
console.log(filterWithJustType[0].payload.trim());
```

this solution ensures that `ActionMap` is the only place where you have to declare types, and everything else will be derived from it.

**UPDATE:**
Article was just published with more examples of this approach https://medium.com/@dhruvrajvanshi/some-tips-on-type-safety-with-redux-98588a85604c

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because it requires the compiler to make the assumption that if some type that extends `Actions` has a `type` member with literal type `S`, then it must be `typeof v1`.

This assumption in general is not safe to make, because `extends Actions` is pretty weak constraint, and this compiles:

```
const v3: { type: "S"; payload: boolean } = { type: "S", payload: false };

const filterWithJustType3 = [v1, v2, v3].filter(findByTypeDoesntWork("S"));
```

As an aside, it does not compile in 2.6 with `strictFunctionTypes` turned on, but type inference is not taking advantage of additional soundness introduced by this option, and it's not clear that it should.

But there is a way to tell explicitly to the compiler that a union member can be unambiguously inferred only from the type of it's `type` member. You just need to establish type mapping yourself:

```
const v1: { type: "S"; payload: string } = { type: "S", payload: "test" };
const v2: { type: "N"; payload: number } = { type: "N", payload: 123 };

interface ActionMap {
    S: typeof v1;
    N: typeof v2;
}

type Actions = ActionMap[keyof ActionMap];


const findByTypeWorks = <T extends keyof ActionMap>(type: T) => (
    action: Actions
): action is ActionMap[T] => action.type === type;

const filterWithJustType = [v1, v2].filter(findByTypeWorks("S"));
console.log(filterWithJustType[0].payload.trim());
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I don't like that compiler doesn't check how accurate ActionMap is, so for example I can change `type` in `v1` to `"X"` and it will compile ok, but will return runtime error. Also writing `<typeof v1>` in ActionMap is only slightly better than writing it in filter :) since it will scale to `number of actions` instead `of number of actions`*`number of filters`, while if it was possible to write it in `findByType` it would only be one place :) bit.ly/runtime-error

Comment: Yes I agree it's not optimal - it would work better if you could somehow move type definitions for  all possible `v1..N` types to ActionMap instead of keeping them with the variables, and declare variables as `v1: ActionMap['S'] = {...}` and `v2: ActionMap['N'] = {..}`.  Not sure if it fits your intended use case or not.